# Создание роли с правами discord.py

Tags: python, discord

```
@Bot.command()
@commands.has_permissions(Administrator= True)
async def start(ctx):
    guild = ctx.guild
    perms = discord.Permissions(send_message=False)
    await guild.create_role(name="muted", Permissions=perms)
    await ctx.send("Успешно")
```

Необходимо создать роль muted без прав на отправку сообщений

Answer (score 3):

Понимаю что это не ответ на вопрос, да и вопроса тут нет. Но в чем проблема создать роль до и выдавать ее на некоторое время? Я создал роль до выдачи наказания, после выдал ее на которое время. Время указано в команде и все получилось.

```py
@bot.command()
@commands.has_role(655461057673822238)
@is_owner()
async def mute(ctx, who: discord.Member, time: int, reason):
    print(f'[command.mute] От {ctx.author}, кого {who}')
    await ctx.send(f'--> {who} получил мут на {time} минут по причине: {reason}')
    await who.add_roles(Object(654796099218833409))
    await who.move_to(None)
    await asyncio.sleep(time * 60)
    await who.remove_roles(Object(654796099218833409))
```

`who.move_to(None)`кикает с голосового канала и `asyncio.sleep(time * 60)` заставляет подождать пока не выйдет время в минутах и тогда уже заберет роль. И все это возможно ради одной библиотеки `import asyncio`

Answer (score 0):

```
@Bot.command()
@commands.has_permissions(Administrator=True)
async def start(ctx):
    guild = ctx.guild
    perms = discord.Permissions(2048)
    await guild.create_role(name="muted", Permissions=perms)
    await ctx.send("Успешно")
```

попробуйте вставить id прав